# Invalid key_frame(I) and P- frame sequence in h264 Binary stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264, keyframe

I am getting video from USB webcam and encoding into h.264 raw stream as follows...

> ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -rtbufsize 200M  -i video="Logitech HD Webcam C270" -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency  -g 30 -s 480x640 -buf
>   size:v 50M output.h264

I am expecting 1-Key frame and 29-P Frame(with SPS/PPS) in output.h264 stream.But I am not getting the expected result.However video is playing fine.

I tried to get Metadata of same file using ffprob ..

> ffprobe -show_frames videofilename.h264 > outputlogfile.txt

Here I can see proper sequence 1-Key frame and 29-P frames.But if we open h264 file in binary reader(I am using HDX) I can see Key/P frames not in proper sequence.

You can download h264 sample and ffprob logs from below links.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ghpkqdc36wdgxr/TimerSample.h264?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdn64004o0udrfk/TimerSample.txt?dl=0

You can find binary sequence of same file from  [here (filtered by start code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pConr.png)

Please let me know whether i am missing some filter. Thank you.

Comment: What sequence do you see?

Comment: Please add ouput.h264, videofilename.h264 and outputlogfile.txt. Otherwise we will be guessing or looking for our "Logitech HD Webcam C270"  cameras - thanks.

Comment: @MarkusSchumann I have added links to the questions. thanks

Comment: @Gyan I have attached  sequence screen shot to question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The highlighted elements in the screenshot show that the bitstream begins with a SPS unit, then a PPS unit, then a SEI unit, followed by slices of an IDR picture, then non-reference picture slices. This is all normal and expected.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i videofilename.h264 -c copy -bsf:v trace_headers -f null -
```

to see a text dump of the parsing of the bitstream.

Comment: "slices of an IDR picture, then non-reference picture slices" exactly .But I am expecting only one I frame (Not IDR)  and 29 P frames. thanks. @Gyan

Comment: Why would the encoded bitstream not start with an IDR?

Comment: Yes you are right. Its should start but my problem is instead of IDR(Which is group of I frames) I need only one I frame and then 29 P frames ... @Gyan

Comment: IDR is not a *group* of I-frames. IDR (instantaneous decoding refresh) simply means an I-frame which tells the decoder to discard all earlier reference frames stored in its buffer. What you're observing is each frame partitioned into slices and separately encoded. If you want each frame encoded as one slice, add `-thread_type frame` to your command.

Comment: I think its my bad . I miss understood IDR Concept as I am new to this domain."-thread_type frame" is giving expected result for me thank you. Really appreciate your effort .. @Gyan